Memory Allocation function is not working properly
My function is not working properly. For example, when I try to add resistor called R1 with the value of 500, and then R2 with the value of 500, and then R1 with the value of 500 again, it gives me the following output:
V  -1984934880 Ohms
R2  500 Ohms
But when I try adding R1 500 and R1 500, it works properly. It outputs that R1 label already exists and that:
R1  500 Ohms
The rest of my code works well as under any other scenario where there is no R1 -> R2 -> R1, it works as expected.
I will appreciate any help. Thank you!
Code:
void handleInsert(LinkedList* circuit) {
    int resistance;
    printf("What's the value of the resistor: ");
    readInputNumber(&resistance);

    printf("What's the label of the resistor: ");
    char labelName[STRING_MAX];
    readInputString(labelName, STRING_MAX);

    Node* current = circuit->head;
    Node* prev = NULL;

    // Check if a resistor with the same label already exists
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(current->name, labelName) == 0) {
            printf("A resistor with %s label already exists.\n", labelName);
            return;
        }
        prev = current;
        current = current->next;
    }

    Node* newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (newNode == NULL) {
        printf("Memory allocation failed.\n");
        return;
    }

    newNode->value = resistance;
    strcpy(newNode->name, labelName);
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if (prev == NULL) {
        circuit->head = newNode;
    } else {
        prev->next = newNode;
    }
}

I tried tweaking with the debug and found where I got it wrong (in function handleInsert).

Show the definition of your Node structure, and show the code that "adds" your resistors instead of describing it.

Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function main and all #include directives, as well as the exact input required to reproduce the problem. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste.

Have you tried running your code line-by-line in a debugger while monitoring the control flow and the values of all variables, in order to determine in which line your program stops behaving as intended? If you did not try this, then you may want to read this: What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems? You may also want to read this: How to debug small programs?

The output suggest the first node is corrupted.

"My function is not working properly" means nothing so you leave the filler out.  Your [mre]  will ideally hard-code the failing test case.
